# await inside an async task?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a method like this:

```
private AsyncResourceGetter _getter;
public Task<string> DoSomeWork()
{
   return _getter.GetAsync();
}
```

I'm thinking of changing it to:

```
public async Task<string> DoSomeWork()
{
   return await _getter.GetAsync();
}
```

What's the difference? what's the right approach here?

Comment: The second one creates a state machine inside DoSomeWork()

Comment: See here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Comment: A source on these topics I'd always recommend is Stephen C : [Eliding async await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Comment: In this particular case, eliding async await is technically fine. Nothing would go wrong here. That said, I still hold to Stephen Cleary’s recommendation of not doing so.